# using pyinstaller keep the fonts on all systems

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I made a GUI using tkinter.

I created onefile exe with pyinstaller, but seted font (font = freesans.ttf)  is not applied to other computers.

I think I need to adddata a font, but I don't understand the answers of pygame or pyqt in cases similar to mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution for adding custom fonts to pyinstaller executables on Windows. You'll need to add your font path to the pyinstaller build with `--add-data` so it can be picked up in the `MEI` folder used by the executable.

```
import ctypes
import sys
from pathlib import Path


def fetch_resource(rsrc_path):
    """Loads resources from the temp dir used by pyinstaller executables"""
    try:
        base_path = Path(sys._MEIPASS)
    except AttributeError:
        return rsrc_path  # not running as exe, just return the unaltered path
    else:
        return base_path.joinpath(rsrc_path)


def load_font(font_path, private=True, enumerable=False):
    """Add the font at 'font_path' as a Windows font resource"""
    FR_PRIVATE = 0x10
    FR_NOT_ENUM = 0x20
    flags = (FR_PRIVATE * int(private)) | (FR_NOT_ENUM * int(1 - enumerable))
    font_fetch = str(fetch_resource(font_path))
    path_buf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(font_fetch)
    add_font = ctypes.windll.gdi32.AddFontResource.ExW
    font_added = add_font(ctypes.byref(path_buf), flags, 0)
    return bool(font_added)  # True if the font was added successfully
```

Then in your main Python file (or wherever you're trying to use freesans), you can load the font like so

```
import tkinter.font as font

custom_font = 'Freesans'  # check the name your system uses, I'm just gussing here

if custom_font not in font.families() and not load_font('<path/to/freesans.ttf>'):
    custom_font = 'Fallback font name here'  # if freesans can't be loaded...
```

An important note is that my `fetch_resource` function can be used for just about any app asset you need, like icons or images. Just remember to add them to pyinstaller via `--add-data`, and wherever you're using them in your Python file, get their paths via `my_icon = fetch_resource('path/to/my_icon.ico')` for example/ That way, you can use `my_icon` when running as a script or when running as a built exe!

Comment: On computers without FreeSans.ttf installed, the default font is changed. Am I missing something?
load_font('<C:Location/of /my /font/ files/FreeSans.ttf>')
pyinstall --onefile -w --add-data="FreeSans.ttf;." xxx.py I am using this command.

Comment: I'm not sure - that shouldn't affect the default fonts available to Tkinter...

Comment: using it by modifying the spec file like inserting an icon in pyinstaller. thank you bro

Comment: Right on - glad to hear it worked out!