# How to solve "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html" with excutable python created by Pyinstaller

Tags: python, jinja2, pyinstaller

This is the complete error:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html

I have the latest versions of all programs and libraries.
When creating "main.py" executable, it saves the .exe inside the disc folder, but when I run it, I get that error. Apparently pyinstaller did not include the index.html.
I want everything to be inside the executable.
I have all the files in the same folder.
I tried `-pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py` but it does not work.

my files are: main.py , index.html

Comment: There's info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74157641/8512262) that I think might help! The `fetch_resource` function I describe there is what you want!

Comment: Have you got the answer, if so, please comment it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76415769/jinja2-exceptions-templatenotfound-index-html-error-pyinstaller-exe