# How to pack txt file with python project to .exe by pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

For example I have file lang.txt in directory with main.py in me project. When i compile it to .exe and execute it i take an error about that this file isnt found. Or there is other method to store text in file and use it?

tryed just pyinstaller --onefile main.py and flet pack main.py in my project with flet

Comment: I have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74157641/8512262) that might help. It technically deals with loading a font file into a pyinstaller exe, but the principle is the same. Pyinstaller `--onefile` bundles everything into a temp dir at runtime, so you need to be able to access that dir (and your files). The key point is the bit about `--add-data`, which is how you tell pyinstaller to include your file(s)