# Facing prob. while importing font in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

**Description:**
So I am using customtkinter for my project and I used Armin Grotesk font in my project the problem is if the project is running on my system it works like a charm as soon as I transfer the files over to a new pc the font disappears, I think sans-serif replaces it.

**Expecting:**
A solution maybe like installing the font in the background without the user knowing or maybe a method through which I can transfer the font file.

Comment: I have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74157535/using-pyinstaller-keep-the-fonts-on-all-systems/74157641#74157641) that might help. However, it does assume that you're bundling your app into an executable with Pyinstaller.

Comment: have you researched this topic before? because there are open source projects for this task like https://pypi.org/project/tkextrafont/

Answer (score 0):

The tkinter behavior you describe is how it is designed to work - if you try to use a font that tkinter doesn't have access to then it will substitute another font. Tkinter itself has no ability to install missing fonts (how would it even know where to download it from?).

If you need to install fonts on some other machine, you'll need to find an external library to do that for you.

Comment: I do know the fact that tkinter cant install fonts and I know that I have to use external libraries I just want a workaround maybe a ps1 commad line that can install the font or smthing