# Importing assets in Python doesn't work after making a build

Tags: python, build, pyinstaller, assets

So I used this code here below to import a sound to my PyGame project, and while normaly it works alright, whenever I make a build and run it, that "current path" seemingly changes to something completely different. What can I change to make it work properly?

```
current_file_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
current_directory = os.path.dirname(current_file_path)
buttonSound = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(current_directory, "assets\\button.wav"))
```

Only thing that came to my mind is to check what is that new "current path". Apparently it changes to 'C:\Users[My Username]\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI44802' with the last folder not even being there, for some reason

Comment: I have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74157641/8512262) that should help. The gist is that when you bundle your app with pyinstaller, you need to do some work to fetch your assets from the right place (i.e., that MEI folder - a new one gets created each time your app runs, so the `fetch_resource` function in the linked answer handles that!)